# To number the blanks in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to make a memory test of sentences.

Given a sentence, the code picks 3 random words and make them into blanks. It also prints out the 'answers'.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.               # original sentence
```

I am working on:

```
import string, re
from random import sample

original = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
o_list = original.split()
picked = sorted(sample(range(1,len(o_list)), 3))

new_sentence = []

for idx, word in enumerate(o_list):
    if idx in picked:
        word = " _____ "
    else:
        word = word
    new_sentence.append(word)

new_sentence = " ".join(new_sentence)
print (new_sentence)

answers = [str(idx+1) + '.' + o_list[w] + '  ' for idx, w in enumerate(picked)]
print (''.join(answers))
```

Outputs:

```
The quick brown  _____  jumps over  _____  lazy  _____     # question sentence
1.fox  2.the  3.dog.
```

I want to number the blanks, like:

```
The quick brown  1. _____  jumps over  2. _____  lazy  3. _____
```

I tried a regex way but it only replaces them into blanks:

```
new_sentence = re.sub(r' _____ ', ' ', new_sentence)
```

What's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: how about `word = str(idx+1) + ". _____ "`

Comment: @furas I think that won't work because you'll be printing out "which word you're in" (e.g., if the first word you replace is the word in index 4, the number 4 will be outputted, instead of the expected number 1).

Comment: @DanteCulaciati you are right - I didn't check how all code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import string, re
from random import sample

original = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
o_list = original.split()
picked = sorted(sample(range(1,len(o_list)), 3))

new_sentence = []
word_count = 1

for idx, word in enumerate(o_list):
    if idx in picked:
        word = f"{word_count}. _____ "
        word_count += 1
    else:
        word = word
    new_sentence.append(word)

new_sentence = " ".join(new_sentence)
print (new_sentence)

answers = [str(idx+1) + '.' + o_list[w] + '  ' for idx, w in enumerate(picked)]
print (''.join(answers))
```

You simply add a word counter and increment it each time you replace a word.

Output:

```
The 1. _____  brown fox jumps 2. _____  the lazy 3. _____ 
1.quick  2.over  3.dog.
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
for idx in range(len(picked)):
    new_sentence = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z0-9 ] _____ ", " %d. _____ " % (idx + 1), new_sentence, 1)
```

output is like

```
'The quick brown 1. _____  jumps over 2. _____  lazy 3. _____ '
```